# Normed space of dimension $> 1$

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space of dimension > 1. Prove that each $\epsilon > 0$ exist $x,y \in X$ such that $\left \| x \right \| = \left \| y \right \| = 1 $  and $ 0< \left \| x-y \right \|< \epsilon$

Comment: Hint: Consider, for example, any vector $z$ that is not a multiple of $x$, and $y(t)=(x+tz)/|x+tz|$ for $t\in\Bbb{R}...$

Comment: $x,y$ must be different, I think

Comment: The problem is when X has infinite dimension